# Room with Flowable: initialize database if it's empty

Tags: android, kotlin, rx-java, rx-java2, android-room

I have following `@Dao`, that provides `Flowable<User>` stream:

```
@Dao
interface UsersDao {
  @Query("SELECT * FROM users")
  fun loadUsers(): Flowable<List<User>>
}
```

I want the subscriber of the stream to receive updates of the database as soon as some change happens there. Subscribing to Room's `Flowable` I will get that feature out of the box.

What I want is following: if database is empty I want to perform a web request and save users into database. The subscriber will automatically receive new updates that had just happened.

Now I want the client of the repository not to be aware all of the initialization logics: all he does - he performs `usersRepository.loadUsers()`. And all of these magic should take place inside the repository class:

```
class UsersRepository @Inject constructor(
    private val api: Api,
    private val db: UsersDao
) {

  fun loadUsers(): Flowable<List<User>> {
    ...
  }
}
```

Of course I can use following approach:

```
fun loadUsers(): Flowable<List<User>> {
  return db.loadTables()
      .doOnSubscribe {
        if (db.getCount() == 0) {
          val list = api.getTables().blockingGet()
          db.insert(list)
        }
      }
}
```

But I would like to construct the stream without using side-effects (`doOn...` operators). I've tried [`composing()`](http://reactivex.io/RxJava/2.x/javadoc/io/reactivex/Flowable.html#compose-io.reactivex.FlowableTransformer-) but that didn't help much. Been stuck on this for a while.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You could apply some conditional flatMaps:

```
@Dao
interface UsersDao {
    @Query("SELECT * FROM users")
    fun loadUsers(): Flowable<List<User>>

    @Query("SELECT COUNT(1) FROM users")
    fun userCount() : Flowable<List<Integer>>

    @Insert // I don't know Room btw.
    fun insertUsers(List<User> users) : Flowable<Object>
}

interface RemoteUsers {
     fun getUsers() : Flowable<List<User>>
}

fun getUsers() : Flowable<List<User>> {
     return
         db.userCount()
         .take(1)
         .flatMap({ counts ->
             if (counts.isEmpty() || counts.get(0) == 0) {
                 return remote.getUsers()
                        .flatMap({ users -> db.insertUsers(users) })
                        .ignoreElements()
                        .andThen(db.loadUsers())
             }
             return db.loadUsers()
         })
}
```

Disclaimer: I don't know Room so please adapt the example above as the features of it allow.

Comment: Was looking something like `ignoreElements()`! Thanks, sir!

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your insert() call is async and also handles updates, you could do something like this:

```
fun loadUsers(): Flowable<List<User>> = userDao.getAllUsers().switchIfEmpty { api.getAllUsers().doOnNext { userDao.insert(it) }  }
```

You could also use some:

```
fun loadUsers(): Flowable<List<User>> = userDao.getAllUsers().flatMap { it->  if (it.isEmpty()) api.getAllUsers().doOnNext { userDao.insert(it) } else Flowable.just(it)}
```

Advice:

You should consider the case when the data is stale, therefore you need to go another way around, do a network request and database call at the same time. Whichever observable finish first, take the result and display it. Updating database should be right after network call is done.

Comment: The problem with these 2 approaches is following: the client (subscriber of the stream) won't get further updates that would take place in database, because both `switchIfEmpty` and `flatMap` would substitute the original stream, which was aware of db changes. Also, these approaches still have "side effect" operators (`doOnXXX`). Thanks for the answer.