# Download data if db is empty with RxJava2

Tags: android, kotlin, retrofit2, rx-java2, android-room

I need to check if database is empty and if it is, then download data with retrofit2, select what I need and insert it to database and finally return inserted data from database. I have tried to do it with this example https://stackoverflow.com/a/48478847/5184417, but I can't figure out the part with inserting data to database. It gives an error about return of flatmap that insert to database doesn't return anything.

I have this piece of code

```
fun getEmployees(): Flowable<List<Employee>> {
    return employeeDao.getEmployeeCount()
            .take(1)
            .flatMap { counts ->
                if (counts.isEmpty() || counts[0] == 0) {
                    Api.getAPIService().getDepartments()
                            .flatMap{ response ->
                                employeeDao.deleteAll()
                                for (departments in response.Departments) {
                                    if (departments.Name == "AR") {
                                        for (employee in departments.employees) {
                                            employeeDao.insert(employee)
                                        }
                                    }
                                }

                                state.postValue(RepositoryState.READY)
                            }
                            .ignoreElements()
                            .andThen(employeeDao.getAll())
                }
                employeeDao.getAll()
            }
}

interface ApiService {
    @GET("departments")
    fun getDepartments() : Single<Departments>
}

@Dao
interface EmployeeDao {
    @Query("SELECT * FROM employees")
    fun getAll(): Flowable<List<Employee>>

    @Query("SELECT count(1) FROM employees")
    fun getEmployeeCount(): Flowable<List<Int>>

    @Insert(onConflict = REPLACE)
    fun insert(employee: Employee)
}
```

Thanks for any help!

Comment: see this  Answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/51552283/6685154

Comment: Thanks, but this won't react to db updates

Comment: i update  my Answer  again check it ;)

Answer (score 0):

flatmap is used to chain the observable. It's syntax is:

> observable1
>             .flatmap(i-> {
>              return observable2;}
>             )

So the point is that you should return an Observable inside flatmap and that Observable will be propagated down(I mean observable 2 in above code). One possible solution is that make employeeDao.getAll() to return a flowable OR some how just wrap the output of employeeDao.getAll() inside Observable.just() or Observable.create() or whatever method you know.

EDIT: You must return an observable inside flatmap, you are not using any return statement.

Comment: getAll() is returning flowable. Error is in second flatmap which doesn't return anything and that's why I'm asking what to do.

Comment: What if you add following code statement: return employeeDao.getAll();